# Render an view into an image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm using the camera to take pictures and when i press a certain button the  `createImage` method will be called. In here i'm trying to render an view called `containerView` into the image taken by the camera in `previewImageView`. However the issue is that the image in the camera is the size `1080x1920` and the `containerView` is a different size depending on the device. For instance on a iphone 6 it will be `375x503`. How can i make sure that these two is rendered proberly together like in the below quick illustration?

in my code the `containerView` is very small in the bottom corner.

**My Code at the moment**

```
func createImage() -> UIImage {

    //Get the taken image
    let fullSizeImage = previewImageView.image

    let newOverLayHeight = fullSizeImage!.size.width / self.containerView!.frame.width * self.containerView!.frame.height

    print(newOverLayHeight)

    //Render containerView to image
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(fullSizeImage!.size.width, newOverLayHeight));
    self.containerView!.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let overlayImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    //Merge these two images

    let newSize = CGSizeMake(fullSizeImage!.size.width, fullSizeImage!.size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize )

    fullSizeImage!.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height))

    //draw overlayImage on top of fullsizeImage

    overlayImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0,fullSizeImage!.size.height - newOverLayHeight, overlayImage!.size.width,overlayImage.size.height), blendMode:CGBlendMode.Normal, alpha:1.0)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```

**What i want**

[image]